# How to change a project icon in VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a VSTS project and I'd like to change the icon, however I don't see any options in the edit project settings page?

[image]

Comment: You can change the logo if you turning off the new navigation preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, I don't believe you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it now it was fix, https://twitter.com/jnowwwak/status/1112616572517040128

[image]
You need to click project icon.